# how to override local connection string with azure connection string

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database

I am using appsettings.json in .Net core project for connection string. My connection string is :

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "OT_DB_Connection": "Data Source=108.***.**.**;Initial Catalog=O*******s;User ID=O*******s;Password=O*********$"
  },
```

In startup.cs i am accessing connection string with key like this

```
   options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("OT_DB_Connection"));
```

I deployed this code on azure and i have sql database on azure.
After deployment how my website will use the connection string of azure ?
How to override the local connection string with azure connection string at run time.

Comment: It's not a good idea to create a new account to ask [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52050417/4916627) a second time. This can result in a ban.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the following article:

[Multiple Environment Configuration Files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

You can have multiple appSettings e.g. 1 for you local environment and 1 for Azure etc. When you publish your app to Azure, you can add an application setting called ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT and add a value that maps to your environment for your app to pick up the correct configuration. If you have an appSettings.**Azure**.json file you can set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to **Azure** and it will use that configuration file.

If you do not want to take this approach, you can also override the connection string directly in Azure as show in the picture below. This is accessible under your app service -> Application Settings -> Connection Strings. You will want to override OT_DB_Connection.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but how connection string is overrided automatically ?

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what you're asking. Please note, that once you've overridden the connection string in Azure as mentioned above, you will not need to do it again.

Comment: I am asking about the second approach you mentioned 
' you can also override the connection string directly in Azure as show in the picture below '.How this technique works ? If you can Please elaborate that would be a great help.

Comment: I've explained it in my answer. Go to your app service in Azure -> Application Settings -> Connection Strings. Add a key called "OT_DB_Connection" and then add a value that corresponds to the connection string you want to use in Azure. The picture shows everything.

Comment: That means there is no change required in code for this ?

Comment: Nope, not at all if you will override directly in Azure.

Comment: I have to add connection string named "OT_DB_Connection" in the list of connection string as shown in image above right ?