# How to override local connection string with azure connection string at runtime?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database

I have written connection string in appsettings.json for .Net core project. My connection string is :

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
"OT_DB_Connection": "Data Source=108.***.**.**;Initial Catalog=O*******s;User ID=O*******s;Password=O*********$"
```

},

I am accessing this connection string in startup.cs file as shown below.

```
options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("OT_DB_Connection"));
```

Now i deployed this website on azure and i have separate database on azure and i want that my website will to connect to azure database at runtime by overriding the local connection string.

Please suggest how i can achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding the connection string to the AppSettings on your Azure App Service? A simple Google [found this web page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure#connection-strings)

Comment: I already go through this link. But it does'nt help.

Answer (score 0):

You may create application setting entry (in Azure) with name `ConnectionStrings:OT_DB_Connection` and read it as

```
Configuration["ConnectionStrings:OT_DB_Connection"]
```

This code will read both and you appsettings value for local development, and overrided value in Azure App Service.